# Sum and product of digits equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let P(N) and S(N) be the product and the sum of all the digits of integer N
>   respectively. How many solutions does the following equation have?
>   P(P(N)) + P(S(N)) + S(P(N)) + S(S(N)) = 2019.

It seems the problem should be broken into cases (two digits numbers,three digit numbers, etc.). However, I have no clue how to calculate P(S(N)) as the digits carry sometimes. Thanks!

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Wim9WJeDTHQ

Comment: It would be interesting to search for the smallest example.  You need to get most of the $2019$ out of the $P(P(N))$ term.  Note that $P(N) \lt N$ because if $N$ has $k$ digits the largest $P(N)$ can be is $9^{k-1}$ times the first digit of $N$ while $N$ is greater than $10^{k-1}$ times the first digit.

Comment: closest we can get P(N) to is 2016 like 22222337 the hard part is adding 1's to this to get only small factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infinitely many. If we make sure $N$ has at least one $0$ digit, $P(N)$ will be $0$ as will $P(P(N))$ and $S(P(N))$  We will also make sure $S(N)$ has a $0$ digit so $P(S(N))=0$.  Then all we need is $S(S(N))=2019$.  As the sum of digits is like a logarithm, $N$ will be huge.  One number $K$ with $S(K)=2019$ is $\frac 19(10^{2019}-1)$, which has $2019\ 1$s.  We will multiply it by $10$ to get the $0$ digit we want, so our number becomes $K=\frac {10}9(10^{2019}-1)$  Now we want a number with this sum of digits, so we follow the same strategy, getting 
$$\frac 19\left(10^{\frac {10}9(10^{2019}-1)}-1\right)$$
Now we multiply this by $10^n$ for any $n \ge 1$ and we have the zero digit we wanted.  We could get smaller examples by using this strategy with larger digits.